# The player is not moving in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((HEIGHT, WIDTH))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):  
        self.tiled_map = load_pygame('map/map.tmx')
        self.tilewidth = self.tiled_map.tilewidth
        self.tileheight = self.tiled_map.tileheight
        self.CAMERA = self.tiled_map.get_object_by_name("player")
        for layer in self.tiled_map.layers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x, y, tile in layer.tiles():
                    if (tile):
                        self.screen.blit(tile,
                                    [round(x * self.tilewidth - self.CAMERA.x + WIDTH / 2),
                                     round(y * self.tileheight - self.CAMERA.y + HEIGHT / 2)])

            elif isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledObjectGroup):
                for object in layer:
                    if object.image:
                        self.screen.blit(object.image,
                                    [round(object.x - self.CAMERA.x + WIDTH / 2),
                                     round(object.y - self.CAMERA.y + HEIGHT / 2)])
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.pos = [self.CAMERA.x, self.CAMERA.y]

    def update(self):
        pg.display.update()

    def run(self):          
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()    

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()    

    def draw(self):
        pg.display.flip()  

    def events(self):           
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.pos[0] -= 10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.pos[0] += 10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.pos[1] -= 10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.pos[1] += 10
        print(self.pos[0],self.pos[1])
        self.tiled_map.get_object_by_name("player").x += self.pos[0]
        self.tiled_map.get_object_by_name("player").y += self.pos[1]
```

I'm learning python and pygame. I was able to view the map, and the buttons are working, but nothing moves.

I'm launching the game with

```
g = Game() 
g.run()
```

Where is the mistake? Is there anything else that can be changed in the code?

Comment: `self.update()` and `self.draw()` do the same thing (flush the display).

Comment: ok I can delete one. But how to fix the problem

Comment: @lukasz you never draw the player.

Answer (score 0):

The way most games in PyGame work is to re-draw everything on the screen every frame.

Your program draws to the screen during the `load_data()` function - which is only called once, but then never draws to the display again.

Separate the drawing code from the loading code.  Then call the drawing code every frame.

This gives you a loading function *something like*:

```
def Game:
    ...

    def load_data(self):  
        self.tiled_map = load_pygame('map/map.tmx')
        self.tilewidth = self.tiled_map.tilewidth
        self.tileheight = self.tiled_map.tileheight
        self.CAMERA = self.tiled_map.get_object_by_name("player")
        self.pos = [self.CAMERA.x, self.CAMERA.y]
```

And when it's time to draw, do the background and the player:

```
    def draw( self ):
        # Draw the background map
        for layer in self.tiled_map.layers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x, y, tile in layer.tiles():
                    if (tile):
                        self.screen.blit(tile,
                                    [round(x * self.tilewidth - self.CAMERA.x + WIDTH / 2),
                                     round(y * self.tileheight - self.CAMERA.y + HEIGHT / 2)])

            elif isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledObjectGroup):
                for object in layer:
                    if object.image:
                        self.screen.blit(object.image,
                                    [round(object.x - self.CAMERA.x + WIDTH / 2),
                                     round(object.y - self.CAMERA.y + HEIGHT / 2)])

        # Draw the player HERE (maybe)
        # TODO
        # self.screen.blit( player_bitmap, ( player_pos[0], player_pos[1] ) )

        # Flush the updates to the display
        pg.display.flip()
```

It's not clear to me from the code presented in the question, exactly what needs to be done to draw the player bitmap, so I can't provide a good answer on this aspect of the code.

Generally when you write a function it should only do a single thing - load the bitmaps, OR draw the bitmaps.  Not both.